The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'
I have some problems to compile my codes in our build machine. The app consists of .NET framework 4.7.1 class libraries (DLLs). I am upgrading Microsoft.Extensions.Logging and other related Microsoft.Extensions DLLs to version 8.0.0 for these projects. These Microsoft extensions can work with .NET 4.6.2 noted in NuGet packages. It should work with .NET 4.7.1, too.
The code changes are compiled without error on my local PC, but there are errors in some DLLS on the build machine.
The errors are:

The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

and

The type or namespace name 'Logging' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Extensions' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I am guessing we probably need to install something although I thought these packages should be restored by NuGet restore if they are defined in the packages.config.

You probably need the netstandard package, although it seems like it EOL.  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-future-of-net-standard/#for-the-impatient:-tl;dr
This post also refers to NETStandard.Library for the logging: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356802/how-does-microsoft-extensions-logging-work-for-full-net-framework

@Mike That is not reason. The following are dependent packages for logging:
Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces (>= 8.0.0)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (>= 8.0.0)
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions (>= 8.0.0)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options (>= 8.0.0)
System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource (>= 8.0.0)
System.ValueTuple (>= 4.5.0)
